# How can I use Logged in user id in another page?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, profile, pinia, userid

I'm new to using Vue and Pinia
I want to show logged in user first_name & last_name, but when I want to access the user id after logged in, it returns undefined
could you please help me to fix this problem
actually I can access these infomations on the login page, but I want to access them right after login, when redirect to home page and go to other pages

Here is my pinia login store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { axiosAPI } from '../axios'

export default defineStore('login', {
  state: () => ({
    user: [],
    isLoading: false,
    isuserLoggedIn: false,
    token: '',
    userInfo: [],
    isRedirect: false,
    userId: '',
  }),
  actions: {
    async loginUser(values) {
      this.isLoading = true
      await axiosAPI
        .post('user/login', values)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          this.isLoading = false
          const data = response.data.data.payload
          if (data) {
            this.user = data
            this.isuserLoggedIn = true
            this.token = data.token
            localStorage.setItem('token', this.token)
            this.userId = this.user.id
            this.isRedirect = true
            setTimeout(() => {
              window.location.href = '/home'
              this.isRedirect = false
            }, 20000)
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.isLoading = false
        })
        this.getInfo(this.userId)
    },
  },
  persist: true
})
```

here is my profile component:

```
<template>
      <p
        class="sm:text-neutral-950 sm:block hidden sm:text-sm sm:font-light pl-4"
        :class="userProfile"
      ></p>
      {{ userProfile }}
</template>
<script>

import useLoginStore from '../stores/login'
import { mapStores } from 'pinia'
export default {
  name: 'Profile',
  data() {
    return {
      usr: useLoginStore(),
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapStores(useLoginStore),
    userProfile() {
      return `${this.usr.userInfo.first_name} ${this.usr.userInfo.last_name}`
    }
  },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `userInfo` is an array ... why would it have a property `first_name`? Also, nothing ever sets any value for `userInfo` anyway

Comment: thanks for replying, here it is
async getInfo(id) {
      console.log('pinia', id)
      await axiosAPI
        .get(`user/${id}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.userInfo = response.data.data.payload
          console.log(this.userInfo)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }

Comment: `here it is` here what is? unreadable code that should be in the question

Comment: `userInfo` is still shown as an array, why would it have a property `first_name` ... array properties include `length`, `0`, `1`, `2` ... etc ... and some methods like `sort`, `filter`, `map` etc

Comment: sorry, I had to shorten the question lines of code so I lost some important parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default defineStore("login", {
  state: () => ({
    // ... (other state properties)
    userId: localStorage.getItem("userId") || "", // Retrieve userId from localStorage
  }),
  actions: {
    async loginUser(values) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      try {
        // Make a POST request to the login endpoint
        const response = await axiosAPI.post("user/login", values);
        console.log(response);

        // Update the loading state
        this.isLoading = false;

        // Extract user data from the response
        const data = response.data.data.payload;

        // Check if user data is available
        if (data) {
          // Update local state with user data
          this.user = data;
          this.isuserLoggedIn = true;
          this.token = data.token;

          // Store the token in localStorage for persistence
          localStorage.setItem("token", this.token);

          // Update the userId in local state
          this.userId = this.user.id;

          // Store the userId in localStorage for persistence
          localStorage.setItem("userId", this.userId);

          // Set a flag for redirection
          this.isRedirect = true;

          // Redirect to the home page after a delay
          setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href = "/home";
            this.isRedirect = false;

            // No need to call getInfo here; it can be called in the created hook
            // of the home page or another appropriate lifecycle hook
          }, 20000);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle errors and log them to the console
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  },
});
```

To prevent the loss of the userId when the page is refreshed, it's crucial to persist it in the local storage. This ensures that the user's identification remains intact even after a page reload. In the code snippet, the userId is stored using localStorage.setItem('userId', this.userId), ensuring its retrieval and preservation across sessions.

Then Hit the API Call with userId.